# How to populate over multiple columns?

Tags: c#, listview

I am working on an 'attendance' system for the school I work at. I'm using a listview for this, but noticed that there's simply not enough space to house all employees in one list. So I want to add a second column (or at least, another 'instance' of the three columns currently used). How do I manage to get such job done?

I have been thinking about workarounds such as a second listview instance, but that would make things only more complex in my opinion. So I'd like to stick by one.

See image below for visual description of what I want to get; I want the output to first fill the left part of the listview, then the right one.

[image]

And this is the part of my code that it's (probably) about:

```
public void LoadEmployees()
{
    lvEmployees.View = View.Details;
    lvEmployees.GridLines = true;
    lvEmployees.Items.Clear();

    List<Employees> data = database.LoadEmployees();

    for (int i = 0; i < data.Count; i++)
    {
        // Define the list items
        ListViewItem emp = new ListViewItem(data[i].Abbreviation);
        emp.SubItems.Add(data[i].Name);
        emp.SubItems.Add(data[i].Status);

        // Add the list items to the ListView
        lvEmployees.Items.Add(emp);
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, I know that having two grids is sufficient enough as we don't have that many employees around here. And if we do have to add a third grid, then that's okay to me. But the whole thing is to having to prevent it to scroll, as it will be displayed 'statically' on a big TV screen.

Comment: I've added my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `lvEmployees1` and `lvEmployees2` (or left/right), two `ListView`.
We can simply split the `List<Employees> data` in half.

```
lvEmployees1.View = View.Details;
lvEmployees1.GridLines = true;
lvEmployees1.Items.Clear();

lvEmployees2.View = View.Details;
lvEmployees2.GridLines = true;
lvEmployees2.Items.Clear();

List<Employees> data = database.LoadEmployees();

int half = data.Count / 2;

for (int i = 0; i < data.Count; i++)
{
    // Define the list items
    ListViewItem emp = new ListViewItem(data[i].Abbreviation);
    emp.SubItems.Add(data[i].Name);
    emp.SubItems.Add(data[i].Status);

    if (i <= half)    lvEmployees1.Items.Add(emp);
    else              lvEmployees2.Items.Add(emp);
}
```

To create the second "grid", you can simply copy past the element in the designer.